# How to stop tracking commited file in git without deleting it from the repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I need to commit a file and push it to the repository. Then ignore the file without deleting it from the repository.

When someone pulls, he/she should get the commited file, but changes will not be tracked.

Comment: Can you describe the use case? I can't imagine how having a file from version control which I then change (and maybe break) and can't look at the diffs would be useful.

Comment: one program we use in company requires log files. also this program has lot of configurations and other assets. these configurations and assets do not change and we keep a preconfigures setup in github. when someone pulls the repo, he can start using the program without doing ang configuration.

but if the log files are not there, program will not boot up. and there is no reason to track the changes of the log files. we just need them to exists.

Comment: This sounds sensible, but I still don't see what they wouldn't want to see the changes